# How to rotate windows forms in every 20 secs using timer in windows application?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have four windows forms namely, 
form1.vb, 
form2.vb, 
form3.vb, 
form4.vb.

And also i have one master page namely form5.vb. So i have rotate one by one  above four windows forms in form5.vb with every 20 secs . how to do it ?

Comment: What is being displayed? Are they just pictures? Tell us more about what your up to so we can give better answers.

Comment: And you should show what you've tried and decribe the specific problem you face in it.

Answer (score 1):

On a 20 second timer you can call '`BringToFront`' on each form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx

Comment: hi ,now i have four datagridview in one single window form how can i show every single datagridview each and every 20 secs. pls help me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you create a timer and call the function [BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) on each form.

In C#:

```
static int counter = 1;

static void StartRotating()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    myTimer.Interval = 20000; // 20 seconds 
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
    myTimer.Start();
}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                        EventArgs myEventArgs) {
    // you could use a switch statement also
    if(counter==1) form1.BringToFront();
    if(counter==2) form2.BringToFront();
    if(counter==3) form3.BringToFront();
    if(counter==4) { 
        form4.BringToFront(); 
        counter=0; //reset counter
        }
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep an index to know which form is currently displayed and then in the timer elapsed event you can do this

```
            formtoshow.TopMost = true;
            formtoshow.BringToFront();
```